# HBitmap from ID3D11Texture2D

Tags: directx-11

I've been looking for the correct way to do this for a while. [The method outlined here](http://www.cleoag.ru/2013/05/12/directx-texture-hbitmap/) works somewhat (using the fix in the comments) but the colors are actually converted incorrectly. I've been wondering if a method using WinCodec would be better, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that method is perfect for this. The problem was the source format of my texture.